# Оформление бар-чарт таблицы Seaborn Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, matplotlib, seaborn

Как выводить таблицу при помощи в таком формате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А не в таком:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выводить названия стран вертикально, а не горизонтально?
Не обрезая сами названия.
Количество названий и длины их названий мне неизвестны.
Иначе названия смешиваются

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Страна': ['Россия', 'Объединенные Арабские Эмираты ', 'Нарния', 'Средиземье', 'Кек'],
     'Пользователи': [100, 200, 150, 45, 1]})
print(df)
sns.barplot(x='Страна', y='Пользователи', data=df)
plt.title('Количество пользователей')
plt.show()
```

**UPD:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`\n` не сработал в этом варианте

Comment: plt.xticks(rotation=90)

Comment: @strawdog есть другой способ без обрезания названий?

Comment: попробуйте сделать вместо `sns.barplot(x='Страна', y='Пользователи', data=df)` -> `g=sns.barplot(x='Страна', y='Пользователи', data=df)`. А затем `g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

#                                       vv
df = pd.DataFrame(                     #vv
    {'Страна': ['Россия', 'Объединенные \nАрабские Эмираты ', 'Нарния', 'Средиземье', 'Кек'],
     'Пользователи': [100, 200, 150, 45, 1]})
print(df)

sns.barplot(x='Страна', y='Пользователи', data=df)
plt.title('Количество пользователей')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

                                       
df = pd.DataFrame(                     
    {'Страна': ['Россия', 'Объединенные Арабские Эмираты ', 'Нарния', 'Средиземье', 'Кек'],
     'Пользователи': [100, 200, 150, 45, 1]})
print(df)


sns.barplot(x='Страна', y='Пользователи', data=df)
plt.xticks(df.index, df.Страна.str.upper(), 
           rotation=25, horizontalalignment='right', 
           fontsize=7)

plt.title('Количество пользователей')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: такой способ не подойдет, так как мне заранее неизвестно количество стран. А  чем больше стран, тем график более сужается. И писать split для определенной длины названия страны - не подходит

Comment: @Дима я обновил свой ответ

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете воспользоваться методом tight_layout, но я советую заранее задать размеры изображения с "запасом".

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Страна': ['Россия', 'Объединенные Арабские Эмираты ', 'Нарния', 'Средиземье', 'Кек'],
     'Пользователи': [100, 200, 150, 45, 1]})
print(df)
sns.barplot(x='Страна', y='Пользователи', data=df)
plt.title('Количество пользователей')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а каким методом задается размер изображения?

Comment: @Дима https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html

Comment: Если по-простому: `plt.figure(figsize=(20,10)) `  (имейте в виду, что размерность задаётся в дюймах).